# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' when importing video file

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

Making a video player in NextJS using TS. I imported a video file from my src/assets folder and this is the error I am getting.

> error - ./src/assets/video.mp4 Module parse failed: Unexpected
> character '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this
> file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
> See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for
> this binary file)

I researched a bit and found out that the webpack is the issue here. Some of the solutions in Stack Overflow suggests that I should add a custom.d.ts file in my project and add the following:

```
declare module "*.mp4" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

which omits the error caused when importing video files, but the error I am facing is in compile time. Another solution is to add loaders to webpack.config.js. But which webpack.config.js file? I only have one in my node_modules folder, and it is in boxicon. I don't have much experience in changing these types of settings, which might cause big issues. So, how to work around this issue?

Comment: probably you should put the video in `/public` directory in next.js, and add src to your video element for example as `/public/video.mp4`

Comment: So put the assets folder in public directory and then use dynamic import?

Comment: well tried it both ways, putting the assets folder in public and putting the video directly in the public folder, doesn't work.

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: oh sorry. I solved it by importing it like this, <video ref={videoElement} onTimeUpdate={handleOnTimeUpdate}>
          <source src="/assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        </video>

Answer (score 0):

To clarify for any future readers, they didnt need a webpack config file and just needed to change the syntax around for video's src. I ran into this issue too and needed some testing to figure out what the solution was in the comments.

For example:
page.tsx

```
// Assuming the file is under /public
<Video h={"500px"} w={"900px"} link={"/egfile.mp4"}></Video>
```

Component file Video.tsx

```
type Props = {
  h: string,
  w: string,
  showControls?: boolean,
  notSupportedMessage?: string,
  link: string,
  filetype: "video/mp4" | ""
}
export const Video = ({
    h,
    w,
    showControls = true,
    notSupportedMessage = "Your browser does not support the video tag.",
    link,
    filetype = "video/mp4",
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <video 
      style={Style.video}
      height={h} 
      width={w} 
      controls={showControls}>
      <source src={link} type={filetype}></source>
      <span>{notSupportedMessage}</span>
    </video>
  );
};
```

The error appears when trying to use an import statement like we do for images:

```
import egfile from "@/public/egfile.mp4"
```

then

```
<Video h={"500px"} w={"900px"} link={egfile}></Video>
```

Instead, provide the string directly - for next js, the string root "/" refers to /public.